# splitting long long

Tags: c++

How could one "split" i.e. long long type, so that first part of it is in var of type long and second part is also in var of type long.

```
long long long_type = 0xaaaabbbbccccdddd;
```

and in first int I would like to have first half(doesn't matter from what side) of the long_type var and in second var int second half.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous. It depends on what you mean by "split". You can split the *value representation* of your original `long long` or you can split the *object representation* of your `long long`.

If you want to split the value representation, then your question is even more ambiguous due to the fact that your original value is *signed*. How do you intend to split a signed value? What kind of result do you expect? Signed? Unsigned? High-order part signed, low-order part unsigned? Or something else?

For an unsigned value it would look as follows (assuming that the recipient type `long` has the right size for your purposes)

```
unsigned long long long_type = ...;

unsigned long hi = long_type / ULONG_MAX;
unsigned long lo = long_type;
```

If you want to split the object representation, the proper way to do it would be to use `memcpy` (in this case the signedness of the original value is not of importance)

```
long long long_type = ...;

unsigned long hi, lo;

memcpy(&lo, &long_type, sizeof lo);
memcpy(&hi, (char *) &long_type + sizeof lo, sizeof hi);
```

In this case, of course, which part is actually the low-order one and which part is the high-order one will depend on the platform.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: Because apparently I am the only one so far who actually understands the full extent of the issue.

Comment: fair enough, but I didn't mean anything bad. I was just humorous. Thanks for your answer. Most appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend using uint32_t and uint64_t or other fixed width types.

Then use bit operations to split it like:

```
uint64_t long_type = smthng;
uint32_t high = (long_type & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ULL) >> 32;
uint32_t low = long_type & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Comment: But he is specifically asking about `long long`. Why do you change the question to make your answer look better?

Comment: @Nawaz that's ok, I can substitute any type for any, as long as I know the method.

Comment: @piotr although I like "your" method, looking at Nawaz's answer I'm just thinking if "his" ((CHAR_BIT) * sizeof(long)); isn't "more portable" to 32. What're thinking?

Comment: @piotr: If the types have the right sizes, then both `&` operations are totally unnecessary and only obfuscate the code.

Comment: @Andrey yes, now when I look at this second time I see what you mean. Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

```
long a = long_type;
long b = (static_cast<unsigned long long>(long_type) >> 32);
```

Comment: Because parentheses make everything better.

Comment: @TonyK: Because I like parentheses.  They make things more clear to me.

Comment: UB! Right shift on signed type is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @piotr No it isn't.  If the value is negative, the results are implementation defined, but only if the value is negative.  And in practice only two variants exist: zero bits are inserted, or one bits are inserted.  On the other hand, when assigning to a `long`, if the value doesn't fit in a `long`, the results are implementation defined, and may result in a signal, which if not caught may result in program termination.

Comment: @piotr: it's actually *left* shifts on signed types that might result in undefined behavior (basically it's undefined if you don't start with a non-negative value and end with a value that's small enough to still be).

Comment: @Michael Burr: No, piotr's comment is (almost) correct. Right shift on signed type is *implementation-defined*.

Comment: @TonyK, piotr: yup - there's a fine line between UB and IB. Sorry if I came across negatively. I was really just pointing out a bit of related trivia on the shift operator.