# Is there a difference between -1 and ~0?

Tags: c++, c

When comparing a unsigned value, as in this test:

```
if (pos == (size_t)-1)
```

Is this comparison **technically** different from something like:

```
if (pos == (size_t)~0)
```

I am not used to the second variant. That's why I am asking the question. The answer may be rather straighforward if it's yes.

Comment: Well `-1` converted to unsigned is [always guaranteed to be UMAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801069/using-1-as-a-flag-value-for-unsigned-size-t-types/22801135#22801135) I don't think we can say that about `~0` b/c it depends on the underlying representation.

Comment: The (straightforward) answer is no (there is no difference).

Comment: @barakmanos: Then straightforward means wrong?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but very closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The C++ standard guarantees that `size_t` is an unsigned type, that unsigned types obey the usual modular arithmetic rules (where the modulus is two to the number of bits in the value representation of the type, cf. 3.9/4), and thus `-1` converted to `size_t` must be the largest value which that type can represent.

The value `0` is an `int`, and `~0` has all the bits in the `int` representation of zero flipped. The value of that result depends on the representation of `int` on your platform. That value (which may be a trap representation, thanks @Matt McNabb) is then converted to `size_t` (which is done following the rules of modular arithmetic).

In conclusion, whether the resulting values compare equal is implementation defined. (For example, if `int` is represented in two's complement, then the value of `~0` is `-1`, so the two are the same.)

Comment: @KerrekSB You say "depends on the representation of `int` on your platform". Out of interest, what if the inversion happens after the cast i.e. `~((size_t)0)`. Would this remove the dependency on the implementation of the `int`? I.e. would there be stronger guarantees that `(size_t)-1` and `~((size_t)0)` would be equivalent? (Typo fixes from my last comment)

Comment: @Niall: I believe so, though I haven't all the pieces together just now. The `~` operator is defined as one's complement, and the value of an unsigned integer is the binary value of its value representation (this is the part I'm missing), so it follows that one's complement of zero is "all ones", which is the maximal representable value.

Comment: I think it may be required by the standard. From the C++ draft; section 3.9.1, paragraph 7; "The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system. [ Example: this International Standard permits 2’s complement, 1’s complement and signed magnitude representations for integral types. —end example ]" +1 I find this an interesting question/answer pair.

Comment: @Niall: It's certainly hard to see how it could be anything else, especially if you combine 3.9.1/4, 3.9.1/7 and footnote 52. Basically,  an unsigned integer has N value bits, and the value of the bits determines the value of the integer in the usual way. It's really only the signed integers that leave any room for implementation details. (And of course the fact that integers needn't be uniquely represented; they may well have padding.)

Comment: Note that in one's complement, `~0` may be a trap representation (negative zero)

Answer (score 19):

[Assuming (guaranteed by the standard) that size_t refers to an unsigned integer value](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/size_t/), this:

```
if(pos == (size_t)~0)
```

used with the intent to be equivalent to:

```
if(pos == (size_t)-1)
```

is assuming that the machine uses a [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation for negative integers. The standard [**doesn't enforce it**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654159/1938163) so you shouldn't assume it if you want your code to be 100% portable.

Comment: `size_t` is always unsigned.

Comment: C11 _does_ specify how _-1_ is converted to unsigned: 6.3.1.3, paragraph 2. The value is `UINT_MAX`

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour `~0` is signed. `~0 == 0` is likely on a one's complement system, and then the conversion to `size_t` still yields zero. If it were `~0ULL`, that would perhaps be another story.

Comment: I've seen ones compliment machines for which +0 != -0. Whether or not this is standard is not known to me.

Comment: @Joshua Regarding "I've seen ones compliment machines" - curious to know what machine this is? Is there a link you can share for anyone to lookup and potentially purchase?

Comment: @ZeZNiQ: Some ancient Cisco gear back in college. The specific application of IP routing made ones compliment CPUs worth it back in the '90s.

Answer (score 1):

So, in your example *technically* there is no difference whatsoever. Because it is hard to find a compiler that will not optimize operations on literals like `-1` and `~0`. With your example I've got exactly:

```
        ; ...
        movq    $-1, -16(%rbp)
        movq    $-1, -8(%rbp)
        ; ...
```

> Don't be afraid of those `-1`'s, assebmly is typeless ;)

More interesting question is if your example would be:

```
#include <stddef.h>
int main() {
        int var0 = 0;
        int var1 = 1;
        size_t a = (size_t) -var1;
        size_t b = (size_t) ~var0;
        return a ^ b;
}
```

In my case (Kubuntu, gcc 4.8.2, x86_64, `-O0` option) the part of interest was:

```
        movl    $0, -24(%rbp)    ; var0 = 0
        movl    $1, -20(%rbp)    ; var1 = 1

        movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
        negl    %eax             ; 2's complement negation

        ; ...

        movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
        notl    %eax             ; 1's complement negation

        ; ...
```

Looking into Intel's manual:

> #### `NEG` - Two's Complement Negation
>
> Replaces the value of operand (the destination operand) with its
>   two's complement. (This operation is equivalent to
>   subtracting the operand from 0.)
>
> #### `NOT` - One's Complement Negation
>
> Performs a bitwise NOT operation (each 1 is set to 0, and each 0
>   is set to 1) on the destination operand and stores
>   the result in the destination operand location.

My conclusion would be, theoretically, code could differ on some exotic platform and compiler, but otherwise – no. And always if unsure check assembly listing on your platform.